# Medical insurance submission

Tags: health-insurance

Can my medical Dr. refuse to submit a prescription to my insurance for the reason that they aren't compensated enough, when they are contracted with my insurance?

Comment: Please add a country tag. As it stands, the question is both unclear, and likely off-topic.

Comment: do they submit the bills for office visits to the insurance company?

Comment: I would think you need to change doctors regardless of the answer to this question.